# MVVM What the correct way share data from parent view model to child view models?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF application I should share ObservableCollection from parent view model to multiply child view models and child view models should also subscribe on CollectionChanged events. If I pass the collections through the parameters of the constructor of the child model, then their number will grow, possibly in the future.

I considered the Mediator and EventAggregator patterns, but I could not understand how to apply them correctly in my situation.

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     protected void OnPropertyChanged( ... ) { ... }
}

class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChildVM_1> Childs_1 { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<ChildVM_2> Childs_2 { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<ChildVM_3> Childs_3 { get; }

    public void Load( ... )
    {
        // Fill Childs_1 and Childs_2
        foreach( ... )
        {
            object par1 = ...;
            object par2 = ...;
            Childs_3.Add( new ChildVM_3( par1, par2 ) );
        }
    }
}

class ChildVM_1 : ViewModel { ... }
class ChildVM_2 : ViewModel { ... }
class ChildVM_3 : ViewModel
{
    // Selected value for ComboBox
    public SubChildVM SelectedValue
    {
        get{ ... }
        set
        {
            ...
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // Items Source for ComboBox
    public ObservableCollection<SubChildVM> SubChilds { get; }

    public ChildVM_3( object par1, object par2 )
    {
        object par3 = ...;
        foreach( ... )
        {
            if( ... )
            {
                 SubChilds.Add( new SubChildVM_1( par1, par2, par3 /* Here I need MainViewModel.Childs_1 */ );
            }
            else
            {
                 SubChilds.Add( new SubChildVM_2( par1, par2, par3 /* Here I need MainViewModel.Childs_2 */ );
            }
        }
}

abstract class SubChildVM : ViewModel{ ... }
class SubChildVM_1 : SubChildVM 
{
     // Selected value for nested ComboBox;
     public ChildVM_1 SelectedValue 
     {
        get{ ... }
        set
        {
            ...
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
     }

     // IsEnabled property for ComboBoxItem.
     // Determines whether this item can be selected from the drop-down list.
     public bool IsEnabled
     {
        get{ ... }
        set
        {
            ...
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
     }
     // Items Source for nested ComboBox
     // What the best way to retrive this reference from MainViewModel???
     public ObservableCollection<ChildVM_1> Childs_1 { get; }

     public SubChildVM_1( object par1, object par2, object par3 )
     {
          IsEnabled = Childs_1.Count > 0;
          if( IsEnabled )
          {
              // Set default selected value
              SelectedValue = Childs_1.First();
          }
          Childs_1.CollectionChanged += UpdateIsEnabled;
     }

     private void UpdateIsEnabled( ... )
     {
         IsEnabled = Childs_1.Count > 0;
     }
}

class SubChildVM_2 : SubChildVM 
{
    // Same as SubChildVM_1 but with ChildVM_2 references.
}
```

Comment: You could use an IoC container and wrap your data in its own class then have all ViewModels retrieve the respective data class

Comment: Google "dependency injection". You don't pass a parent into your child, you create a contract (interface) that provides the functionality your children need. You then implement that functionality with your parent (or some other object) and use a dependency injection framework like Ninject or Autofac to inject the implementation into the children.

Comment: What do you mean by "their numbers will grow"?

Comment: @Andy Number of constructor parameters.

Comment: I think I would be inclined to worry about an increasing number of parameters when the problem occurs. I'm not so sure dependency injection is a great way forward here. You need a different type or interface per different collection in order to register it and mainviewmodel is instantiating these things. I think a factory pattern is probably more appropriate.  If you want flexibility then you could consider passing a reference to mainwindowviewmodel into each one. The child viewmodel can decide which bits it wants to reference then.